# Unknown firmware header for ARM device

Tags: firmware, arm

I've obtained a vendor firmware which I'd like to look at in more detail. It appears to be wrapped in some kind of wrapper that I've never seen before. It's not a DFU footer, or a DfuSe header and I can't see anything obvious. Any ideas very welcome. `srec_info` seems to think it's "Motorola S-Record" but this is clearly a padded binary format, ending with what looks like a SHA256 hash:

```
0000000 0001 0000 0200 0000 0000 0003 0000 0400
0000010 0000 0000 0005 0000 3000 0000 0000 0031
0000020 0000 3200 0000 0000 0101 0010 0020 0403
0000030 18ff 0300 ff04 0018 0000 0000 ffff ffff
0000040 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
*
0000200 df03 fae3 dcb6 3e5e 1dd8 d3b8 8805 a692
... firmware blob ...
0003410 0073 0065 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
0003420 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
*
0003500 0001 0000 0200 0000 0000 0003 0000 0400
0003510 0000 0000 0005 0000 3000 0000 0000 0031
0003520 0000 3200 0000 0000 0101 0010 0020 0403
0003530 18ff 0300 ff04 0018 ffff ffff ffff ffff
0003540 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
*
00035e0 8bce 56ef c6db d0db a6ce 9cce 9cce 9cce
00035f0 9cce 9cce 9cce 9cce 9cce 88d1 55aa 1385
0003600
```

Any ideas very welcome, thanks!

Comment: It's certainly possible, but *quite* improbable, for a SHA256 hash (or any other common hash) to contain 8 repetitions of the same '9cce' word.

Comment: The end looks like an interrupt vector table. Which architecture is this for?

Comment: Can you share the entire firmware file or a link to grab it. I've reversed the firmware format for a smart pen and there are similarities. For example, the "0001", "0003", "0005" and following values look similar to the firmware updater "commands" that the smart pen uses to specify load addresses, sizes, and checksums.

Comment: Hi David. I can't share the entire file as I'm working with the vendor on another potentially security issue, sorry. Vendor bootloader commands are certainly one possibility, I'm open for ideas. Thanks!